# How can a Nautilus script be run for an empty directory?

Tags: script, context-menu, nautilus

I have a Nautilus script that can create multiple directories at once using `mkdir` with the option `-p`. The script is effectively the following:

```
directoryStructure="$(zenity --title  "make directory structure" --text "Enter the directory structure (e.g. (\"foo/bar\"))" --entry)"
if [ ! -z "${directoryStructure}" ]; then
    mkdir -p "${directoryStructure}"
fi
```

How could I get this script to run for an empty directory? I know how to get it running only by accessing the context menu of an existing file. How can I get the script running when there are no files?

Comment: Doesn't the "Scripts" context menu sub-entry appear when clicking on an empty area of the window? At least it does on Nautilus 3.4.x.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for taking a look. I do not see the submenu "Scripts" in the context menu for an empty area in Nautilus 3.10.1.

Comment: Welp, looks like GNOME did away with yet another useful feature in Nautilus. You might be able to assign a shortkey to your script, though. Check out the corresponding section in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-can-i-install-a-nautilus-script/236415#236415) ('Assigning a keyboard shortcut to the script').